# How to change the value in List<T> list2 without changing the value in List<T> list1 when using list1.AddRange(list2)?

Tags: c#, list, addrange

My code

```
list1.AddRange(list2);
foreach (var item in list2)
{
    item.Value--;
}
```

when I change the value in list2, the values added to list1 before are also changed

how can the value in list1 not be changed?

Comment: Don't add the same item to both lists. Add a copy/clone to the 2nd list.

Comment: It depends. Maybe records can help you here as they behave like value types and are usually copied automatically.

Comment: You might also want to read: [What is the difference between a reference type and value type in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5057267/what-is-the-difference-between-a-reference-type-and-value-type-in-c)

Comment: @Magnus how can i make a copy of list2, i tried using `CopyTo` but it doesn't seem to work

Comment: Not a copy of the list, a copy of the items you add.